# I want to load image Using method of NSURLConnectionDelegate and NSURLConnectionDataDelegate

Tags: nsurlconnection

I want to load images into connectionDidFinishLoading method and the method func connection(_connection: NSURLConnection, didReceive: Data) is not getting called

```
class ImageDownload: UIImageView,NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate
{
    var imageSaved:UIImage!
    var imageDownloaded:UIImage!
    var connection2:NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection()
    var data: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    var urlstring:String = ""
    var fileURL:URL!
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    var pathPlist:String!

    func downloadImage()
    {
        let imgdownload :String =  "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + urlstring
       // let urlnew: NSURL = NSURL(string: imgdownload)!
        //print(urlnew,"url")
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: imgdownload)!
         let request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
      //  let request2: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urlnew as URL, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 60.0)
        connection2 = NSURLConnection(request: request1 as URLRequest, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
        connection2.start()
    }

    func setURL(url:String) -> Void
    {
        print(url,"url")
        urlstring = url
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(url)
        print(fileURL,"fileurl")

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path)
        {
            let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path)
            print("file exists")
            self.image = image
        }
        else
        {
           downloadImage()
            //let imgdownload :String =  "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + url
           // let request = URL(string: imgdownload)
           // let myUrl = NSURL(string: imgdownload)
            //print("image loaded")
           // self.image = self.imageSaved
        }
    }

        func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didReceive response: URLResponse)
        {
            print("in didReceive response\n")
            self.data = NSMutableData()
        }
        func connection(_connection: NSURLConnection, didReceive: Data)
       {
        print("in didReceive data\n")

        self.data.append(data as Data)
        print(data,"image data is")
        }
    func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: Error)
    {
        print("connection error = \(error)")

    }
    func connectionDidFinishLoading(_ connection: NSURLConnection)
    {

    }
}*
```

Comment: The formatting of your post is a bit off. Maybe you could fix that? And provide some context, like the programming language or environment you are using? Also, please remove the pointless commented lines from your code example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Swift syntax for NSURLConnection, so there's a nonzero chance I'm missing something subtle with the delegate method names, but off the top of my head, I see a couple of bigger problems:

- Why are you using NSURLConnection in Swift?  Every version of iOS that supports Swift also has NSURLSession.  Just use the shared session, and your behavior will be almost identical to NSURLConnection.
- You're using HTTP URLs.  In all recent versions of iOS, you have to add special bits to your Info.plist if you want your app to be able to access HTTP URLs.  I do not recommend doing that.  Just use HTTPS.

You can get free TLS certs for HTTPS from Let's Encrypt.   My guess is that as soon as you set that up and switch to an HTTPS URL, your problems will go away even with the existing code.  But you should still be using NSURLSession.